# Installation of django-scheduler: $python manage.py runserver returns KeyError: u'__module__'

Tags: django, module, calendar, schedule, keyerror

I installed django-scheduler with pip (https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler) and I edited settings.py as in the tutorial. When I run $python manage.py runserver I got this:

```
python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_scheduler-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/schedule/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from schedule.models.calendars import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_scheduler-0.7.5-py2.7.egg/schedule/models/calendars.py", line 110, in <module>
    class Calendar(with_metaclass(ModelBase, *get_model_bases())):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 617, in with_metaclass
    return meta("NewBase", bases, {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 71, in __new__
    module = attrs.pop('__module__')
KeyError: u'__module__'
```

I tried to reinstall Python (2.7), Django (1.7) and the app. I need a calendar app to my project and this seems the most complete.

Thanks.

Comment: Please format your post properly. Script output and code excerpts should always be formatted as code, i.e. using fixed width font. That makes the reading thereof much easier.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue.  It turned out to be a problem with the version of python's `six` I had installed.  I was using `six` version `1.6.1`, and when I upgraded to version `1.9.0` it took care of this error.  Run:

```
pip-2.7 install --upgrade six
```

Comment: I also then had to install a couple other dependencies: `icalendar` and `future`.

Answer (score 0):

```
run this script using djago-getversions.py

import pip
 installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
 installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
 for i in installed_packages])
  print(installed_packages_list)
----------------------------------------------------

check your django installed versions

after that compare or reinstall like these versions:

please check your this version:

[
   'adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4',
   'apt-xapian-index==0.45',
   'chardet==2.0.1',
   'colorama==0.2.5',
   'command-not-found==0.3',
   'debtagshw==0.1',
   'defer==1.0.6',
   'dirspec==13.10',
   'django-classy-tags==0.6.1',
   'django-cms==3.0.12',
   'django-mptt==0.6.1',
   'django-sekizai==0.8.1',
   'django-treebeard==3.0',
   'django==1.6.1',
   'djangocms-admin-style==0.2.5',
   'djangocms-link==1.5',
   'djangocms-snippet==1.4',
   'djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.4.3',
   'dnspython==1.11.1',
   'duplicity==0.6.23',
   'html5lib==0.999',
   'httplib2==0.8',
   'iniparse==0.4',
   'lockfile==0.8',
   'lxml==3.3.3',
   'mercurial==2.8.2',
   'mysql-connector-python==1.1.6',
   'mysql-python==1.2.3',
   'mysql-utilities==1.3.5',
   'oauthlib==0.6.1',
   'oneconf==0.3.7',
   'pam==0.4.2',
   'paramiko==1.10.1',
   'pexpect==3.1',
   'pillow==2.3.0',
   'pip==7.1.0',
   'piston-mini-client==0.7.5',
   'pycrypto==2.6.1',
   'pycups==1.9.66',
   'pycurl==7.19.3',
   'pygments==1.6',
   'pygobject==3.12.0',
   'pyopenssl==0.13',
   'pyserial==2.6',
   'pysmbc==1.0.14.1',
   'pysqlite==2.6.3',
   'python-apt==0.9.3.5ubuntu1',
   'python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2',
   'pyxdg==0.25',
   'reportlab==3.0',
   'requests==2.2.1',
   'sessioninstaller==0.0.0',
   'setuptools==3.3',
   'six==1.5.2',
   'software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0',
   'south==1.0.2',
   'system-service==0.1.6',
   'tortoisehg==2.10',
   'twisted-core==13.2.0',
   'twisted-web==13.2.0',
   'unity-lens-photos==1.0',
   'urllib3==1.7.1',
   'version==0.1.1',
   'virtualenv==13.0.1',
   'wheel==0.24.0',
   'wxpython-common==2.8.12.1',
   'wxpython==2.8.12.1',
   'xdiagnose==3.6.3build2',
   'youtube-dl==2015.7.7',
   'zope.interface==4.0.5'
]
```