# Key error with installation of Django-organizations

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to installing django-organization. I tried using pip and got the following error (Same error when using the Git package).

I'm using the cloud 9 platform with python 1.11 and python 2.7.

Thanks a lot for the help

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> 
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in 
execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", 
line 324, in execute django.setup() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup 
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate 
app_config.import_models(all_models) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models 
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name) File 
"/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module 
__import__(name) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/organizations/models.py", line 26, in <module> from .abstract 
import (AbstractOrganization, File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/organizations/abstract.py", line 37, in <module> from .base import 
OrgMeta, AbstractBaseOrganization, AbstractBaseOrganizationUser, 
AbstractBaseOrganizationOwner File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/organizations/base.py", line 186, in <module> class 
OrganizationBase(six.with_metaclass(OrgMeta, AbstractBaseOrganization)): 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 617, in with_metaclass 
return meta("NewBase", bases, {}) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/organizations/base.py", line 74, in __new__ return super(OrgMeta, 
cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 81, in __new__ module = 
attrs.pop('__module__') KeyError: u'__module__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar question ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717502/installation-of-django-scheduler-python-manage-py-runserver-returns-keyerror)) looks like the problem is Python's `six`. Try this:

```
pip-2.7 install --upgrade six
```